# How do you import backup data into JIRA

Tags: import, jira

Im trying to move my JIRA to a self hosted server from one that was hosted for me. I have backed up the data to xml but how do I import the data into my new Jira?

**Just needed to get xml from Atlassan then back up was no problem -Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jira 4.x there is a restoring utility, that is available in administration console. See [this link](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Restoring+a+Project+from+Backup) for more details.

Comment: I have followed this already but have had no success. I am trying to move from a jira the was hosted by  Atlassian (the url blah.onjira.com), and am trying to move the information over to a different jira hosted internally.  I don't know if this can be done even but any in site would be help full.

Answer (score 0):

A standard JIRA "Restore from XML Backup" under Admin. If you were using Crowd with onjira and don't want to with your own hosted JIRA, make sure that the onjira folk added your user info to your XML backup. You'll also want to make sure you have the credentials for at least one user with system admin permission, not just jira admin.